# Decode this uncommon cipher

Tags: cipher

Can you decode this simple cipher?  Full explanation required as usual.

`STPVR WTSEP KQ VRE ATVREP UA FYDE QDLXTFDEP`

If no one has cracked it in a couple of days, I'll add a hint or two.

Good luck!

Comment: By the way, it's "cipher".

Comment: I suspect by the speed below people are using cipher-cracking software.  Which means you know the answer, but you're not providing a full explanation of it.

Comment: Hi Tim, and welcome to the site! We love seeing people posting original puzzles, however it might be worth reading through [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do), to improve your puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, yes, we all know that

> **DARTH VADER IS THE FATHER OF LUKE SKYWALKER**
>
>  it's a simple substitution cipher.  most common letter in English is E, and most common word is THE.  with one 3 letter word in your cipher text, ending in "E" which is very common in your cipher text, VRE->THE is a decent guess.  R and S are also common, and P is also common in your text, giving a good guess that it's R or S.  "KQ" suggests a common two letter word, and Q appears a couple times so not an uncommon letter; KQ probably is "OR" or "IS".  Put all that together and you have
>
>  __RTH ___ER IS THE __THER __ ___E S______ER
>
>  It's not a long drive from there to the answer; "A" and "T" are pretty common, probably one of them a vowel and one a common consonant (L or N), and a few shots in the dark (plus I just watched Rogue One) and the answer shapes up quickly thereafter.

Comment: Well ok, I'll give it to you since you at least explained how you got there.